# What is consuming our tenants storage space?

Tags: sharepoint-online

We have suddenly hit out storage quota of 6 TB. We added 1TB more and it was consumed immediately. We set the site in question to Read Only but that didn't work because we added an additional 1TB and it was also consumed immediately. We now have 0% available and don't know what action to take besides deleting large / stale sites which won't release storage right away. How do we identify which site is consuming all of the space so quickly?

Comment: Are you not able to filter the sites list in the admin center to determine the largest sites? It's possible that SharePoint allows you to upload more than your storage quota by a certain percentage and then this "appears" like it's being consumed immediately but the large data set has already been uploaded?

Comment: Yes, we can sort by largest to smallest site, but that doesn't show us last activity. When we sort by last activity, it shows Aug 31, but I know that isn't true because of the storage issue as well, the audit logs show sept 1st last activity

Comment: As stated above, maybe SharePoint allows you to exceed your storage allocation by a certain percentage. Therefore when you're increasing it, it is seemingly hitting the new quota very quickly. Have you contacted Microsoft support?

Comment: we have not contacted support yet. When I export all sites, it shows 13.5TB total Storage Used. But the meter only goes up to 7.5TB. How are we able to exceed our storage quota this much?

Comment: This is a question I imagine only Microsoft support can answer. If you are concerned about users using excessive amounts of storage, you can set storage limits on individual SharePoint sites.

Comment: Turns out there were multiple licenses activate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our tenant had a combined storage of about 15 TB before the two disabled licenses below expired on May 31st and were "Disabled" at the end of August (90 day grace period in the expired stage). Both of the disabled licenses combined equals about 7.5 TB of storage, and once officially “Disabled” it immediately revokes that storage capacity. Which cut our existing storage in half in one day, explaining how we 'magically' sky rocketed our usage within the last month.

In order to bring our storage back, it was suggested to reactivate the two previous licenses we had. Or, in some cases if we go too far into the disabled period, those licenses will need to be purchased again. Otherwise, we would need to backup and delete about half of our tenant, which may not be feasible since 80-90% of the sites in our tenant are still active to this month.

[image]